Dynamically load functions from all files in a directory in Clojure
Say I have a directory structure:
- src
-- scraper
--- scrapers
---- scraper_a.clj
---- scraper_b.clj
---- scraper_c.clj
--- scrape.clj

In each scraper_x.clj there are three functions, fetch, collect, parse that I need to parse to a function in scrape.clj called scape which takes the three functions and fetches the source HTML, collects the elements from the HTML, then parses into an appropriate JSON format.
Is there a good way to dynamically load these three functions from all files in the src/scraper/scrapers directory to be utilised in the main function?

Hi! Welcome in. I think what you're looking for is require (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require). What have you tried?

@Harold Hey! Thanks for the response :)
I think require is right, but I just am not sure how to use it load the functions into another function.
Something like:
(def dir (clojure.java.io/file "src/scraper/scrapers")) (def scrapers (file-seq dir))
(defn load-scraper [file]  "Use require on file to load desired functions"   (nil) )
(defn -main []   (map load-scraper scrapers))

I see, so the idea is to be able to install a new 'scraper' by putting a source code file in the sub directory? And then the top-level file always runs them all? It's a slightly unusual arrangement, but definitely possible. The code in your comment isn't really that far off. If I were you, I'd actually try it, and then include the real code in the question. That would allow someone to help you fill the gaps.
